# Incremental sum by Categories/Status

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, cumulative-sum

I have mysql table:

```
id |  datetime  | status | etc
----------------------------
 1 | 2020-03-03 | P
 2 | 2020-03-08 | N
 3 | 2020-03-12 | S
 4 | 2020-03-12 | N
 5 | 2020-03-13 | N
 6 | 2020-03-13 | N
 7 | 2020-03-13 | S
 8 | 2020-03-14 | S
 9 | 2020-03-14 | S
10 | 2020-03-14 | S
11 | 2020-03-14 | S
12 | 2020-03-14 | S
13 | 2020-03-14 | S
14 | 2020-03-15 | S
15 | 2020-03-15 | S
16 | 2020-03-15 | S
17 | 2020-03-15 | N
```

I need to show up the growing of the cases by status, so i did:

```
SELECT DATE(date_created) as date, status, COUNT(*) as total FROM mytable WHERE id>0 GROUP BY DATE(date_created), status ORDER BY date_created ASC
```

And i've implemented this php code:
Each for-time could be the same day, I think I'm getting error on that, look at my code:

```
$Return = array('d'=> array(),
                'P' => array(),
                'N' => array(),
                'S' => array());
$diff = 0; $oldDay = ''; $lastDiff = -1;//used at the end code

foreach($selectData as $key => $val){
    $dayMon = date('d/m',strtotime($val['date']));

    if($dayMon!=$oldDay){//changed the day
        if($oldDay!=''){//not 1st time
            //set previous date total or 0 to status not used
            foreach($listStatus as $temp){
                $Return[$temp][$key-1-$diff] = isset($Return[$temp][$key-2-$diff]) ? $Return[$temp][$key-2-$diff] : 0;
            }
        }
        $Return['d'][] = $dayMon;
        $lastDiff = $diff;
        $diff = 0;
        $listStatus = array('P','N','S');
    } else{
        $diff++;
    }
    $oldVal = isset($Return[$val['status']][$key-1-$diff]) ? $Return[$val['status']][$key-1-$diff] : 0;
    $Return[$val['status']][$key-$diff] = $oldVal + $val['total'];

    //remove status used that day
    $listStatus = array_diff($listStatus, array($val['status']));
    $oldDay = $dayMon;
    $lastKey = $key;
}
//set previous date total or 0 to status not used
foreach($listStatus as $temp){
    $Return[$temp][$lastKey-lastDiff] = isset($Return[$temp][$lastKey-1-lastDiff]) ? $Return[$temp][$lastKey-1-lastDiff] : 0;
}
```

I´m getting some 3 first lines ok but some error on next ones, according:

```
Day 03/03 = had P=1, N=0, S=0
Day 08/03 = had P=1, N=1, S=0
Day 12/03 = had P=1, N=2, S=1
Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in mypage.php
Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in mypage.php 
Notice:  Undefined offset: 3 in mypage.php
Day 13/03 = had P=, N=, S=
Day 14/03 = had P=, N=, S=
Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in mypage.php
Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in mypage.php 
Notice:  Undefined offset: 5 in mypage.php
Day 15/03 = had P=, N=, S=
```

Comment: Did you really intend `$$diff++;`?

Comment: It was wrong, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can compute the running count directly in the query, using window functions:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(date_created) as date, 
    status, 
    COUNT(*) as total,
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER(PARTITION BY status ORDER BY DATE(date_created)) as running_total
FROM mytable 
WHERE id > 0 
GROUP BY DATE(date_created), status 
ORDER BY DATE(date_created), status
```

Note that I fixed the `ORDER BY` clause so it operates on an expression that belongs to the `GROUP BY` clause rather than on `date_created`.